# How to solve mounted partition error in Debian 7

Tags: linux, debian, mount, ntfs, ext

I installed MATE on Debian 7 (LXDE), and encountered problems with both ntfs and ext4 partitions when I mount any partitions (ntfs, ext) using MATE file manager (Caja). I don't recall how it was with LXDE.

```
# mkdir X
mkdir: cannot create directory `X': Operation not permitted
# lsattr somefile.txt 
lsattr: Inappropriate ioctl for device While reading flags on somefile.txt
```

Please help.

Comment: What result do you get if you run `sudo mkdir`?

Comment: mkdir: cannot create directory XXXX Operation not permitted

Comment: Could you post the output of `mount -v` and tell us on in which directory you are getting this error?

Comment: Of course, thanks for asking:
# mount -V ntfs dev/sda3 /media/N
mount from util-linux 2.20.1 (with libblkid and selinux support) -- but nothing was mounted.

Comment: You accidentally posted the output of `mount -V`. Please post the output of `mount -v` (lowercase `v`)

Comment: Thanx, here it is: # mount -v 
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,relatime,size=10240k,nr_inodes=214579,mode=755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,size=411684k,mode=755)
/dev/disk/by-uuid/4e444302-bc6b-4cf4-b3b3-1d8978eb9680 on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,user_xattr,barrier=1,data=ordered)

Comment: AND: tmpfs on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=5120k)
tmpfs on /run/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=1906740k)
rpc_pipefs on /var/lib/nfs/rpc_pipefs type rpc_pipefs (rw,relatime)